# Bokeh shows plot blurred on windows

Tags: python, windows, plot, alias, bokeh

I am using bokeh for plotting. With my current settings, bokeh shows some text and lines kind of blurred (anti-aliased?). This is not really noticeable on my monitor, but on some projectors, especially when doing screenshots and inserting them into presentations, it looks weird.

As requested, a minimum working example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600, 
           title="TestTitle", x_axis_label = "Length [cm]", y_axis_label="Height [m]")
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = "normal"
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "12pt"

show(p)
```

I am using **Windows 7** and tried this in the current versions of **Chrome** and **IE**. **Python 3.6**, **bokeh version 0.13.0**. The first image is taken from the example, the second is taken from my real code:

[image: blur1]
[image: blur2]

I tried different figure sizes, but the problem persists - maybe I am trying the wrong ones? Anything I can do about this, except simply trying different sizes until something "works"? Setting px instead of pts seems to make it worse...

Comment: Bokeh does not use or depend on Matplotlib in any capacity. All rendering is done by the JavaScript library BokehJS, in the browser. In any case, as requested for SO questions, please supply a *minimal, complete, reproducing examople*. In addition, since it's entirely possible this is platform/browser dependent, detailed version information about browser, platform, bokeh versions etc. are needed. It's not possible to speculate at all without much more information.

Comment: @bigreddot: You are right of course - I was confusing it with seaborn.

Comment: @bigreddot: I added a minimal complete example and more information.

Comment: I am working with your software conditions. I get blurred lines in some cases as well. For example drawing a figure of 350x350 I get blurred lines, but if I use 400x400 the are well plotted. If you avoid italic font styles on titles with small font size they will look better too.

Comment: @bigreddot thanks for your input. I added Windows to title / tag since this seems to be OS-specific. If anyone is interested in further investigating, this might have to do with the windows screen scaling function or Windows ClearType, but unfortunately, I don't have time to further investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the text, it is rendered on to a raster HTML canvas, and the details of how this is done are entirely dependent on the browser canvas implementation. (FWIW things look better on any browser on OSX than the above image.) There's not anything we can to change how a specific browser renders text, and not much I can suggest except to make much bigger canvas sizes if you need to show something extremely magnified.

Regarding the aliasing of the axes and tick marks, I can't reproduce anything like that on any OSX browser (Safari, FF, or Chrome). It definitely appears to be a Windows-specific issue. It's possible there are issues that could be addressed, e.g a different HiDPI setting, or half-pixel offsets, but it would take investigation to try and determine what can be done. A Github issue with details would be appropriate, but I can't speculate when it might be addressed (we are under-resourced and no core contributors are regular windows users).